# show contents of doc in wikipage

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, wiki

I have a word-document (in a sharepoint-library, same site) library whose contents  I would like to show in a wiki-page.
So, not just a link to the document but actually see the contents of the document in the wikipage, in such a way that, if the document is updated, these changes are visible in the wiki-page.

Is this possible in SharePoint Online Professional?
We use SharePoint Online Professional and Office 365 Professional (in a mixture of Office 2010 and 2013)

--edit--

I got it! Just used the pageviewer web part en set it to the URL of the document in webapp.

I set it the whole time to file. Stupid me.

Comment: What part of the content you need to display? a TOC? Summary? list of titles? Or you want to display all the document (in that case won't be simpler to use office web apps)?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Ideally I  want to see a specific chapter of the document. Seeing the whole document would allready be superb. I want visitors of my wiki to see the contents of that document without having to navigate elsewhere.

Comment: What a coincidence. I was asked the same, but I have also the "joy" of doing this with SharePoint 2007.

Comment: There is another way. Open your webapp doc. Klik on File en choose 'Share'. I have an option that says 'Enclose' (literal translation from dutch). When I click that I get the possibility of generating an iFrame. Some options are available (size, to print or not to print and such). I paste the HTML that is generated into the source HTML of my page. And it looks wonderful!

Comment: there is a problem. Your content would then be "detached" from the actual document content. If you update the page, the document won't be updated etc.

Comment: Well, that is not a requirement. Actually, I like itthat way. If you need the document to be editable, just use the pageviewer web part en set it to the URL of the document in webapp. Then you CAN edit it, using the webapp or your Office....

Comment: If you update the page, the document won't be updated etc. – SPArchaeologist yesterday                  That! is a problem.... Did not read well... Oh well, pageviewer webapp it is....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you could benefit from Office Web Apps which simply means you could open these in browser (not an actual WikiPage), one alternative could be relying on a building an Event Handler on the document library and using Open XML SDK v 2.0 in a Sandbox solution to keep the Wiki page Content field synchronized with the document.

But your problems don't end here, as you need to account for complex structure of Word documents (practically specifying which content effectively to publish in the wiki body), styles, to mention a few.

Eric White is the ultimate expert, have a look at its blog and series on articles around Open-Xml SDK available starting from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956524(office.14).aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/03/24/modifying-an-open-xml-document-in-a-sharepoint-document-library.aspx

Comment: @c-marius  I do have webapps but how to open webapps within the wikipage?

Comment: webapps open in their own application page (_layouts)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Page Viewer web part one of the options is to view a file.  This works fine for PDF but I have not managed to get it working with Word docs.

http://www.sharepointsharon.com/2010/10/embedding-office-docs/ provides a great write up on what can and cannot be achieved.